# Multiple Criteria Lookup

Tags: excel

I've been working on this spreadsheet all weekend and have not came up with what needs to work. I have three tables, one that has a SKU, one that has a KIT number, and a cross reference table. Basically I am trying to find the KIT number by referencing the cross reference table. However, the problem I am facing is that in the cross reference table there are more than one of the same KIT number's and SKU's. For example, one KIT number may have more than one same SKU and vice versa. I got it down to some basics, I need figure out a way to take the KIT number from Table A and take the SKU from Table B and find where both of the numbers are in the cross reference table.

`VLOOKUP` will not work in this case. I've tried `INDEX`, `MATCH`, and a combination of both.

Any help on this would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your three tables are 1) Customer Orders with KIT No's. 2) Inventory with SKU's, and 3)KIT/SKI reference table (which parts are required for a kit). I think you might want to know which SKU's you need to order, and which ones you have on hand, for the orders you have.

My steps to solve this would be:

1. Get required quantity onto reference sheet by kit number
2. Sum by SKU the new required quantity column
3. Compare to stock on hand

Firstly, I would add a required quantity column to your reference table, which looks up for each SKU, whether there is a customer order with the same KIT number. This could be done with a sumproduct formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((OrderKitNoCol=RefKitNoCell)*(OrderQuantityCol))
```

Where:

```
OrderKitNoCol is the column on your customer orders page, with the KIT's on it
RefKITNoCell is the cell next to the formula, which has the kit number in it on the reference page
OrderQuantityCol is the column on the order page that has quantity (this can be blank, if it's only ever 1's
```

Now, every item in your possible kits, has the number of them that are required to fufil the orders next to it.

Next, on your inventory list, you need to summarise the new column on your reference sheet, for each SKU

So create a new column, and use sum product again, but this time doing it on SKU

```
=SUMPRODUCT((RefSKUCol=InventSKUCell)*(RefSKUReqCOl))
```

Where:

```
RefSKUCol is the column on the reference page with the SKU's in it
InventSKUCell is the cell next to the formula that has the unique SKU
RefSKUCol is the column with the previous formula we just created, on the reference sheet, with the number of parts required
```

This gives you a total number required, now, on your inventory sheet, you have required number of parts, and available number of parts. Hopefully this is everything you need.

Comment: It's confusing anyway.  But I have three tables altogether, one with our inventory, our SKU, another with orders from the customer,  kit numbers,  and our table with kit numbers that go with the SKU inventory. I was thinking have a key column but wasn't sure how to look up the kit number. I was thinking I could find a was to run through the list of kit numbers and compare them against the cross reference table, but each formula I tried came back with an error.

Comment: ok, I get it now. SKU's are individual components, KIT's are collections of components, and your reference table has the join, as in which kits require which components. You want to know, if a customer has ordered a kit, whether you have the components in stock? (this sounds like a data base question, not an excel one, but I'll leave that for now, and we'll try and solve in excel). I'll have a think, and update my answer.

Comment: Also, if this can be done in a VBA script, that would work to. We are trying to stay away from a database for now. I can make this work easily in a database with a `WHERE` clause and call it a day. But, they do not want that right now.